# Passing Chunk Size to ItemReader aggregated in another Custom ItemReader

Tags: spring-batch

I have created a custom Item Reader just like

```
public class AggregateItemReader<T> implements ItemReader<List<T>> {

   private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(AggregateItemReader.class);

   private ItemReader<AggregateItem<T>> itemReader;

}
```

When I call the reader from step, I pass the chunk size but that chunk size is not being passed to ItemReader inside AggregateItemReader and it reads all the records mentioned in the query. Could you please let me know how to pass chunk size to ItemReader inside another Reader

Answer (score 0):

An item reader is not aware of the chunk size. It is the step that calls the reader and decides when the chunk is complete. So in your case, neither the `AggregateItemReader` nor the delegate can get this info, it is up to you to pass this info at configuration time to both of these components.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud. I think I miscommunicated the question. Actually I do not want the item reader to know about the chunk size. The step should run in chunks i.e. if the chunk size is 5, item reader should take 5 records , give it to processor and writer should write it. In my case all the records are read at once.